Puppeteer not found in laravel-pdf
I am trying to generate a PDF based on HTML code in my Laravel project, I installed spatie/laravel-pdf ^1.5 using composer. The problem seems to be with puppeteer but I'm unsure of what the issue might be.
The $data variable in the updated function of the Pdf model is sent HTML code in a string which is modified and then converted into a Pdf by the spatie/laravel-pdf package, however when trying to generate a PDF an error raises saying that Puppeteer is not found. Installing Puppeteer using npm i -g puppeteer does not change the output of the errors.
composer.lock
        {
            "name": "spatie/laravel-pdf",
            "version": "1.5.0",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/spatie/laravel-pdf.git",
                "reference": "8c880bf8d386b9580fcac6c5b99b2d3a6b1becbf"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/spatie/laravel-pdf/zipball/8c880bf8d386b9580fcac6c5b99b2d3a6b1becbf",
                "reference": "8c880bf8d386b9580fcac6c5b99b2d3a6b1becbf",
                "shasum": ""
            },
            "require": {
                "illuminate/contracts": "^10.0|^11.0",
                "php": "^8.2",
                "spatie/browsershot": "^4.0",
                "spatie/laravel-package-tools": "^1.16.1",
                "spatie/temporary-directory": "^2.2.1"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "ext-imagick": "*",
                "larastan/larastan": "^2.7.0",
                "laravel/pint": "^1.13.7",
                "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.10",
                "orchestra/testbench": "^8.18",
                "pestphp/pest": "^2.30",
                "pestphp/pest-plugin-arch": "^2.5",
                "pestphp/pest-plugin-laravel": "^2.2",
                "phpstan/extension-installer": "^1.3.1",
                "phpstan/phpstan-deprecation-rules": "^1.1.4",
                "phpstan/phpstan-phpunit": "^1.3.15",
                "spatie/image": "^3.3.2",
                "spatie/laravel-ray": "^1.33",
                "spatie/pdf-to-image": "^2.2",
                "spatie/pdf-to-text": "^1.52.1",
                "spatie/pest-expectations": "^1.5",
                "spatie/pest-plugin-snapshots": "^2.1",
                "spatie/pixelmatch-php": "^1.0",
                "wnx/sidecar-browsershot": "^2.0"
            },
            "type": "library",
            "extra": {
                "laravel": {
                    "providers": [
                        "Spatie\\LaravelPdf\\PdfServiceProvider"
                    ],
                    "aliases": {
                        "LaravelPdf": "Pdf"
                    }
                }
            },
            "autoload": {
                "files": [
                    "src/Support/functions.php"
                ],
                "psr-4": {
                    "Spatie\\LaravelPdf\\": "src/"
                }
            },
            "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
            "license": [
                "MIT"
            ],
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "Freek Van der Herten",
                    "email": "freek@spatie.be",
                    "role": "Developer"
                }
            ],
            "description": "Create PDFs in Laravel apps",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/spatie/laravel-pdf",
            "keywords": [
                "laravel",
                "laravel-pdf",
                "spatie"
            ],
            "support": {
                "issues": "https://github.com/spatie/laravel-pdf/issues",
                "source": "https://github.com/spatie/laravel-pdf/tree/1.5.0"
            },
            "time": "2024-04-08T11:11:24+00:00"
        },

composer.json
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "awcodes/filament-tiptap-editor": "^3.3",
        "filament/filament": "^3.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^11.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.9",
        "spatie/laravel-pdf": "^1.5"
    },

Pdf model
Imports
use Spatie\LaravelPdf\Facades\Pdf as PdfGen;
use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::updated(function ($data) {
            $html = $data->content;
            $html = '<div class="tiptap-editor"><div class="ProseMirror">'.$html.'</div></div>';
            $html = '<style>'. file_get_contents('css/awcodes/tiptap-editor/tiptap.css') .'</style>'.$html;
            $html = '<style>'.file_get_contents('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css').'</style>'.$html;
            $dom = new \DOMDocument();
            $dom->loadHTML($html);
            $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                $src = $image->getAttribute('src');
                $image->setAttribute('src', public_path($src));
                $type = pathinfo(public_path($src), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $data = file_get_contents(public_path($src));
                $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
                $image->setAttribute('src', $base64);
            }
            $html = $dom->saveHTML();
            $html = str_replace('<html>', '', $html);
            $html = str_replace('<head>', '', $html);
            if (file_exists('output.pdf'))
                unlink('output.pdf');
            $pdf = PdfGen::html($html)->save('output.pdf');
            file_put_contents('output.html', $html);
        });
    }

What I've done
Using just the normal ->save()
$pdf = PdfGen::html($html)->save('output.pdf');

Error:
The command "node "C:\Users\user\homestead\code\filament2\vendor\spatie\browsershot\src/../bin/browser.cjs" "{""url"":""file:\/\/C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1426089947-0494949001713261683\\index.html"",""action"":""pdf"",""options"":{""path"":""output.pdf"",""args"":[],""viewport"":{""width"":800,""height"":600},""displayHeaderFooter"":false,""printBackground"":true}}"" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: C:\Users\user\homestead\code\filament2\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Adding ->setNodeBinary()
$pdf = PdfGen::html($html)->setNodeBinary("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe")->save('output.pdf'); // Verified that this is using the correct node path.

Error:
Call to undefined method Spatie\LaravelPdf\PdfBuilder::setNodeBinary()

Using ->withBrowsershot()
$pdf = PdfGen::html($html)->withBrowsershot(function (Browsershot $browsershot) {
    $browsershot->setNodeBinary("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe");
})->save('output.pdf');

Error:
The command ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\user\homestead\code\filament2\vendor\spatie\browsershot\src/../bin/browser.cjs" "{""url"":""file:\/\/C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\831105329-0121756001713262165\\index.html"",""action"":""pdf"",""options"":{""path"":""output.pdf"",""args"":[],""viewport"":{""width"":800,""height"":600},""displayHeaderFooter"":false,""printBackground"":true}}"" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: C:\Users\user\homestead\code\filament2\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdtemp 'undefined\temp\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXXXX'] { errno: -4058, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'mkdtemp', path: 'undefined\\temp\\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXXXX' }

Adding ->setNpmBinary() and ->newHeadless()
The command ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\ic10\homestead\code\filament2\vendor\spatie\browsershot\src/../bin/browser.cjs" "{""url"":""file:\/\/C:\\Users\\ic10\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\805633131-0807926001713262416\\index.html"",""action"":""pdf"",""options"":{""path"":""output.pdf"",""args"":[],""viewport"":{""width"":800,""height"":600},""displayHeaderFooter"":false,""newHeadless"":true,""printBackground"":true}}"" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: C:\Users\ic10\homestead\code\filament2\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdtemp 'undefined\temp\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXXXX'] { errno: -4058, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'mkdtemp', path: 'undefined\\temp\\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXXXX' }

Using ->setIncludePath() inside of the ->withBrowsershot() function
$pdf = PdfGen::html($html)->withBrowsershot(function (Browsershot $browsershot) {
    $browsershot->setIncludePath("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe");
})->save('output.pdf');

Error:
The command "node "C:\Users\user\homestead\code\filament2\vendor\spatie\browsershot\src/../bin/browser.cjs" "{""url"":""file:\/\/C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2023162371-0794294001713262550\\index.html"",""action"":""pdf"",""options"":{""path"":""output.pdf"",""args"":[],""viewport"":{""width"":800,""height"":600},""displayHeaderFooter"":false,""printBackground"":true}}"" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: C:\Users\user\homestead\code\filament2\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.


The first issue that is there is that you're not supposed to install puppeteer with -g flag. This makes puppeteer a global package, while all you need is project-wide.

Install puppeteer with -D flag, so it will be added into devDependencies of your package.json - since you're not importing puppeteer directly anywhere in your files

npm install -D puppeteer


Make sure you have actual Chrome browser installed. Why? puppeteer uses browser files to emulate browser environment. Apparently, laravel-pdf simulates PDF generation first, and then serves it to us.
2.1. If you're on server environment, you might want to consider a headless Chrome - essentially a browser with no window-based capabilities. You don't need them on a command-line environment.
2.2. If you're using this app on your laptop, you can just install Chrome. puppeteer will find it by itself, same as on the server.

Your code should work now! At least that's what happened for me after hours of trying to figure out what does the error say...


Edit: you might want to check it without the withBrowsershot flag. I'm not certain what it does, but it might replace puppeteer's mechanisms.

Follow the steps below to troubleshoot:

Install Node.js and verify the installation using the command: node -v.
Ensure that Node.js is added to your system's PATH environment variable.
Ensure that the user account you're using has the necessary permissions to execute Node.js commands and access the directories where it's installed.
Restart the terminal and execute the code again.

If these steps don't resolve the issue, you should know that there may be a dependency compatibility problem, and diagnosing it may take time to determine which version is compatible with the framework. Alternatively, you can try using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf. It's easy and simple to integrate and use.

Thank you for your answer, however node is installed correctly and is on the correct version for it to run- as it ran fine before generating the PDF. Using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf is not an option because it doesn't support the necessary styling.
